# Drupal webform is not working for anonymous users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-webform

I am using a webform form as a contact form. This form has following fields: Username, Email, Phone, Title(selectbox), Body. As a authenticated user I can submit form, but anonymous users couldn't submit form. Even, the form's validations are not working. I gave permission for anonymous users. Can I submit form by form_alter. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the permissions settings page in your Drupal site to see if you have given all the required permissions to anonymous users once again? You have might have missed the submit permissions.

Also check out your sites DBLog after you attempt to submit the form in question as an anonymous user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission in the webform, just go to that webform and click the form setting tab and then give permission for anonymous user.